# remove touch event on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, mobile-safari, touch-event

I have a DIV #overlay sitting over DIV #page, but on the #page div, theres a overscroll: auto on an element.

How can I disable all touch events on #page when #overlay is visible and then enable back once #overlay is hidden?

```
<div id="page">touchable content here</div>
<div id="overlay">sits on top of #page DIV</div>
```

This is for mobile webkit only.

Answer (score 3):

**CSS Solution** `div#page { pointer-events: none; }`

---

**jQuery Solution**
your touch event -

```
$('#page').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('blockEvent')) return false;
    //do something...
});
```

when #overlay pops up -

```
// display #overlay
$('#page').addClass('blockEvent');
```

when #overlay closed -

```
// close #overlay
$('#page').removeClass('blockEvent');
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct, I'm talking about disable touch events, not CSS.

Comment: then just give 'pointer-events: none' option when you display #overlay.

Comment: doesn't work on touch device, which is what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: then you should use little bit more complicated method. I'll edit this answer so everyone can see it.